# How to convert data attribute string value to html elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to programming and English language.

I am working on showing the `tooltip` with the dynamic content loading using CSS.

The problem is,

I am pushing the values that contains html element tags to the data-info attribute dynamically using `JQuery`. It is stored as a string and while displaying on `tooltip` it is showing with html tags as strings.

Is there any possible way to show the `tooltip` with the values formatted as HTML.

I'm trying with the following is the code:

```js
 var divContent ;
       $(document).ready(function(){
    
          function getContent(){
              var divAry = [];
              var str;
              divAry.push("<li>ABC</li>");
              divAry.push("<li>DEF</li>");
              str = "<ul>"+divAry.toString().replace(/,<li>/g,"<li>").replace(/,/g,"")+"</ul>";
              return str;
          }
          $('#linkId').mouseover(function(){
              divContent = getContent();
              var jObj = $($.parseHTML(divContent));
              $(this).attr('data-info',divContent);
          });
    
       });
```

```css
.tooltip{
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after{
  background: grey;   
  border-radius: 5px;  
  color: #000;
  content: attr(data-info);
  top: 26px;
  left: 40%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 220px;
}
.tooltip:hover:before{
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  top : 10px;
  bottom: 100%;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid grey;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<a id="linkId" href="#" class="tooltip">Hover here</a>
```

Please anyone get me rid out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show me a screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry I cant do this . I had included my code. please look from this.

Comment: @Maddy Thanks for formatting

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't render HTML elements from text in a pseudo element's content. It's just text. Have you considered [jQuery-UI's Tooltip widget](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)?

Comment: Yes. I am trying but am restricted to add some js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a simple idea to create a `tooltips` message with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var changeTooltipPosition = function(event) {
   var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
   var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
   $('div.tooltip').css({top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX});
 };

 var showTooltip = function(event) {
   $('div.tooltip').remove();
   $('<div class="tooltip"> <li>ABC</li> <li>DEF</li></div>')
            .appendTo('body');
   changeTooltipPosition(event);
 };

 var hideTooltip = function() {
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
 };

 $("span#hint,label#username'").bind({
    mousemove : changeTooltipPosition,
    mouseenter : showTooltip,
    mouseleave: hideTooltip
 });
});
```

```css
 #hint{
  cursor:pointer;
 }
  .tooltip{
  margin:8px;
  padding:8px;
  background-color:grey;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Stackoverflow jQuery Tooltips Example</h3>
<span id="hint">Hover me</span>
```

Comment: Thanks but am restricted to use plugin. Can u give me some other solution, please ?

Comment: I have updated my answer but it requires more css to meet your gender